# Get element by using the value of its associated label

Tags: jquery

I want to get the element of a radio button by using its associated label name.

I know the inner HTML of the label will always be the same. However, the `id` and `value` of the radio button will change. The inner HTML for the label will always be "*Agent*".

Can I use that to get the radio button element using jQuery? If so, how?

```
<input id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder_realRole_14" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ContentPlaceHolder$realRole" value="85" checked="checked">
<label for="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder_realRole_14">Agent</label>
```

Comment: Would `$('label:contains("Agent")').prev()` work for you?

Comment: Or `$('#' + $('label:contains("Agent")').attr('for') )` to find it by associated `id`, regardless of the order of the two.  Note that these are only reliable if other labels don't *also* contain "Label" -- e.g. if there's an earlier label whose text is "Another Label", that will be selected instead.

Comment: Or if your html is more complicated, you can always get the input ID from the label's `for` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get `for` attribute of a `label`

```
var id = $('label:contains("Agent")').attr( "for" );
```

Then use this value as `id`

```
var checkbox = $( "#" + id );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your input elements, get their IDs and check for labels for that ID. Then validate the text of the label:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    var label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');
    if(label.text() === 'Agent') {
        console.log('Found input id for Agent label!');
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3fhumj8/1/